# Sharing a webpage with a filled out form

Tags: html, website, url, forms

Is there a way to share a webpage with a filled out form to someone else? Meaning, let's say the page has a HTML form on it, and I fill it out. Can I share it so that when someone else clicks the link I sent them, they will see the form filled out.

Is this possible to do using HTML and HTTP without using any browser extensions?

Comment: All a form in HTML is is blank form elements. To save the data requires server programming that could save the data and then (perhaps) generate a URL that you can share with someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I believe there's no builtin HTML way to do this. It'll depend on the site. You could check if the specific site you're using supports pre-filling fields using URL query parameters.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not possible.  Webpages, forms and any filled in content are generated from by the code on webserver.  Data you fill will not be saved.  Nothing you could do would allow another person the view the same URL and see what data you filled in.

Technically, this would be possible (with many caveats) if the website and form was *purposefully* coded to do this.  However, in reality, no one would have a logical reason to go out of their way to do this.